# Convert input field clearing from jQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My trouble is not with the action of clearing the input field - I know the `elem.value = ""` I am having more trouble getting the right selector in Javascript.

While my jQuery works fine on the site - all other function are in Javascript, so I would like to keep consistency since it isn't that difficult.

Here is the **jQuery**:

```
function clearShipToFields(){
    $('input.ship_to_value').each(function(){
        this.value = "";
    });
}
```

what I was trying to do in **Javascript** but wasn't working:

```
var shipTo = document.getElementsByClassName('ship_to_value');
//This is where I am stuck - I don't know how to single out input fields only
```

I may need to go a different direction and get the input fields first and then filter by class?

```
var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

For Loop
    inputFields[i].getElementsByClassName('ship_to_value').value = "";
End For
```

**There are multiple fields with the class `ship_to_value` but I would only like to select the `input` field.**

Must also support pre-IE8

Comment: Are you saying you might have more than just an `input` element with that class, and you want to find just the `input`?

Comment: @Jamiec There are multiple classes with the class `ship_to_value` but I only want to select the fields that are `input` elements

Comment: There are some good answers below. But just to add to this: There is nothing wrong combining. I do it all the time; especially for radios and checkboxes. Sometimes readability is better combined. However, if you aren't doing many complex functions, jQuery might be overkill. Otherwise, it's not bad to use whatever tools are in your arsenal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, as such you can access it by index:

```
var shipTo = document.getElementsByClassName('ship_to_value')[0];
shipTo.value = '';
```

If you have multiple elements with that class, you would need to implement your code in a loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ship_to_value');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].value = '';
}
```

> I only want to select the fields that are input elements

In this case you would need to inspect the `tagName` property of the element first:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ship_to_value');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].tagName == 'INPUT' && (elements[i].value = '');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bu2pjtq5/)

Comment: I do believe he is only looking for `input` types -- this will return all types that have the class `ship_to_value`

Comment: I upvoted but would like to add a clarification: Even if you only have 1 element that matches the classname, you still get an array returned and still need to loop.

Comment: @Daved correct - note in the first example the `[0]` to get the first element in the array

Comment: @Tom yeah just saw that comment, example added

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I completely overlooked that bracket. Noted. :)

Comment: Illegal left hand assignment for your last edit - did you mean to use `?` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @Adjit - no its just an attempt at shorthand, what you want is really an `if(elements[i].tagName == 'INPUT') elements[i].value = '';`

Comment: Im leaving my answer there for future visitors, but this is clearly now the *right* answer given IE<8 support.

Comment: got it - yes @Jamiec please do. Thanks for the help guys - while most of my experience is with jQuery I've been trying to lean more on Javascript lately

Answer (score 3):

You may like to look at [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), however be aware to check the support grid in those links.

```
var shipTo = document.querySelector('input.ship_to_value');
```

Comment: Oh wow, thats awesome. I didn't know you had the ability to use those kinds of selectors in JS

Comment: Another good suggestion, but the other answer provides a bit more useful context and example.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `check the support grid`?

Comment: It means that `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are only supported by IE8+. If that's all the legacy support you need, go for it :)

Comment: Ahh gotcha - yeah need to support pre-IE8, but still great answer since I now know of these query selectors

Comment: @Adjit - on those links in my answer, towards the bottom of the page is a grid that describes which browsers support this functionality. The main point is IE8+ as already noted, so just make sure all your users are using browsers for which this function is supported

Comment: Just checked the analytics - about 15% of our users are still pre-IE8

Comment: @Adjit - my condolences.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `querySelectorAll` with a prototype loop to iterate DOM elements.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.ship_to_value"), function(x) {
    x.value="";
});
```

Alternatively you can use `[].forEach.call` instead of `Array.prototype.call`